# How to write aria hidden correctly?

Tags: html

I have very strange question. How correct write `aria-hidden` value: arIa or arEa?
Because on some website i see and first, and second type to writing this attribute.

Comment: Where have you seen *area*?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer in html on some websites. It's strange, yes, but somehow thought. After all, it is possible that it is correct to write differently than I write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aria-hidden` is the correct variant.

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-hidden